# Ubuntu 20.04 Software RAID1 File System Read-Only after power-outage

Tags: ubuntu, raid1

I had a short power outage today and the new server I was working on was shutdown unexpectedly as a result. It still boots up, but it's rendered unusable as it keeps reporting the file-system as read-only.

Nothing really seems destroyed, but the device can simply not be changed to read-write. mdadm details don't seem out of the ordinary:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0

    /dev/md0:
               Version : 1.2
         Creation Time : Thu May 14 18:51:13 2020
            Raid Level : raid1
            Array Size : 488254464 (465.64 GiB 499.97 GB)
         Used Dev Size : 488254464 (465.64 GiB 499.97 GB)
          Raid Devices : 2
         Total Devices : 2
           Persistence : Superblock is persistent

         Intent Bitmap : Internal

           Update Time : Fri Jun  5 14:56:25 2020
                 State : clean
        Active Devices : 2
       Working Devices : 2
        Failed Devices : 0
         Spare Devices : 0

    Consistency Policy : bitmap

                  Name : ubuntu-server:0
                  UUID : c2b17ca4:d623537f:52e4809b:96408cf0
                Events : 6651

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
           0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
           1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
```

But I can't change it to readwrite:

```
mdadm --readwrite /dev/md0

    mdadm: failed to set writable for /dev/md0: Device or resource busy
```

Anyone have any ideas? Nothing I've tried in terms of checking/repairing the filesystem has worked either, and I get the feeling it's either completely lost at this point, or something incredibly simple.

Answer (score 2):

It was quite easy after all!

What had to be done was quickly boot into a recovery cd/ usb, and then download mdadm (apt install mdadm) + assemble the raid (mdadm --assemble --scan), and perform a fsck (fsck.ext4 -f /dev/md0p1) on the filesystem in the array.

The thing to take note of is that if stuff like swap is in the array, like it was for me, you have to quickly check partitions on the drive and determine where your actual filesystem(s) reside to run fsck on those specifically.

Hope this helps others!